# Setting precision for double in java

Tags: java

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000000");
 int a[] = { 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 };
 double sum = 0.000000;
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
 {
    sum = sum + (double) a[i];
 } 
 output1=Double.valueOf(df.format(sum / a.length));
```

where `sum/a.length` value is 3. `output1` is double variable. Now the result I wanted is 3.000000 and it must be store in double variable `output1` but I can't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Although in certain cases it might work, in general there is no way to determine/force the decimal precision of a `double` value, or indeed any [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) number.

If you want decimal precision in Java, use `BigDecimal`. This is even more important if the numbers you work with represent money.

If an approximate result is good enough (and there are lots of calculations where it is), you can use `double` but be aware that it's a binary floating point number and accurate rounding to decimals might not always be possible.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive type `double` is an approximation of a real number, with a sequence of (negative) powers of 2.

Hence the decimal notation 0.2 = 0*2<sup>-1</sup> + ... + 1*2<sup>-4</sup> + ... with an error as one would need an infinite sequence in base 2.

If one wants a precision with the value, one needs BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal oneFifth = new BigDecimal("0.200"); // Precision/scale 3
BigDecimal hundredPlusOnefifth =
      oneFifth.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(501)); // 100.200
```

Using a String in the constructor, BigDecimal can set the precision.

Not so nice writing expressions in BigDecimal though.

With double one might live, while carefully rounding at appropriate points in the code. There always will be a small error and, outputting needs a formatter as the number of digits is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sum` is `int` and you have the result of integer division (because `a.length` is `int`). Just multiply one of those values by 1.0:

```
output1 = Double.valueOf(df.format((sum * 1.0) / a.length));
```

---

With your edited code, your problem is not in obtaining the value of `output1` but how you show it. Don't print `output1` directly, instead use the `DecimalFormat` you used previously:

```
System.out.println(df.format(output1));
```

Comment: I think casting to double would be more obvious

Comment: No the result is again 3.0

Comment: @radai it's basically the same.

Comment: @Guna provide the necessary code to replicate your problem. We don't have a magical crystal ball to foresee what you're doing and how to fix it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `3.0` and `3.00000` are the same in a double variable. When you print it, format it the way you want:

```
 System.out.println( df.format( output1 ) );
```

Comment: This is not C#, there's no `Console#WriteLine` method in Java.